# SQL, difference of max(datetime) and min(datetime) with the result of day

Tags: sql, postgresql, redash

I'm trying to look for the day interval between customer latest booking and oldest booking.

I used `max(booking_date)` to identify a customer's latest booking date, and `min(booking_date)` as the oldest booking date. Both are in datetime format.

I tried using `datediff('day', max(booking_date), min(booking_date))` to find the day interval between the bookings, but it didn't work.

My query:

```
select 
u.id, 
datediff(day, max(b.date), min(b.date))

from bookings b
left join users u on b.user_id = u.id
```

Error message:

> Error running query: function datediff(timestamp with time zone, timestamp with time zone) does not exist

Anyone please assist. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: The first parameter should be `day`, not `'day'`. Also, switch them around if you want a positive number.

Comment: "it returns to be error" - what does that mean? Can you share the query you are using, and the error message you are facing?

Comment: Edited my question, thanks for all your comments